# AppCenter complains and doesn't work to install anything

Tags: updates, appcenter, repositories

Error:

```
Failed to Fetch Updates
This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

Details >
Failed to obtain authentication
```

I do have additional software sources added, a few PPAs and a repository for weechat from the weechat devs.  I'm not sure which one is the culprit (if any).

"sudo apt update" works flawlessly, and I am able to install software through the terminal.  But I am unable to install anything through AppCenter, either free or paid, it simply starts downloading and then fails.

My appcenter.list:

```
deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
```

elementary.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

I also have a patches.list with the following:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic main
```

The other contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ are a PPA for updated versions of mpv, a PPA for an updated version of GIMP, the elementary tweaks PPA, vscode's repository, and weechat's bionic repository.

I will try removing them one by one to see if they are the culprit but I would appreciate any input someone could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was pretty simple.  Just a matter of removing AppCenter:

```
sudo apt remove appcenter
```

and then reinstalling it

```
sudo apt install appcenter
```

Et viola, no more errors!  I think it had something to do with reusing a /home partition from a previous elementary OS (and a few other distros too) install.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as the right answer in order to be visible for everyone that the question is resolved and what is the solution? This is not the first time the appcenter do a problem like this so it can be helpful for somebody else also.

Comment: It won't let me do it yet, three more hours and I'll be able to mark it as the solution.  Apparently some sort of abuse prevention so that you can't just answer your own questions and mark them as answered over and over again.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes, there is such a delay, but I guess no one is in a hurry)