# AppCenter Fails to Fetch Updates, Failed to obtain authentication

Tags: updates, appcenter

The problem I'm encountering appeared identical to this one:

[AppCenter complains and doesn't work to install anything](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21411/appcenter-complains-and-doesnt-work-to-install-anything)

Unfortunately, the fix used there, i.e. removing and reinstalling the appcenter, did not work for me. The contents of `appcenter.list`, `elementary.list` and `patches.list` are all identical to those in the above-cited question. Since the "details" says it's an authentication problem, I doubt this is due to a problematic repository, but for the record here are the files in my own `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory:

```
appcenter.list
appcenter.list.save
elementary.list
elementary.list.save
eugenesan-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-bionic.list
fingerprint-ubuntu-fingerprint-gui-bionic.list.save
patches.list
patches.list.save
philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list
philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list.save
phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-bionic.list
phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-bionic.list.save
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Restarting my computer (and elementary os of course) seems to have cleared up the problem ...

Comment: Can you put the full error message from AppCenter detail?

Comment: The "detail" follows the comma verbatim in the title to this question.

Comment: Restarting didn't help for me... :(